# how to parsing data in addListener javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, maps

I have problem to parsing data from addListener to another function, I try but the 'data' failed to parsing. Can help me guys...

This is my code

```
var data = 'myname';
bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays(data);


function showArrays(event, data) {
   // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
   // MVCArray of LatLngs.
   var vertices = this.getPath();

   var contentString = data;

   // Replace the info window's content and position.
   infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
   infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

   infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: You've pass to listener a result of the call of `showArrays(data)` but you need just reference `bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays);`

Comment: You need to check your syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try it:

```
bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays.bind(this, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, my problem has done.

this code..

```
bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', (function(event){
  var nama = 'myname';
  showArrays(event, nama);
}));
function showArrays(event, data) {
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  var contentString = nama;
  // Replace the info window's content 
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```